# How do I create a dynamic scope where I can pass in an object if possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have these two scopes:

```
  scope :posted_yesterday, -> { where(created_at: (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight)}
  scope :num_posted_yesterday, -> { posted_yesterday.count }
```

What I want to happen is, I would love to be able to calculate many versions of `posted_yesterday`. i.e. `posted_num_days_ago(n)`.

There anyway for me to create dynamic scopes to allow this, or should I just create a method on my `Post` model?

Comment: In short you want to calculate number of posts on a particular day. Right?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want @Anuja

Comment: Instead of making it confusing just create a scope to get total count for a day. And pass an appropriate value i.e. particular day to it.

Comment: See answer given below. If you like "posted_yesterday" instead of "posted_on" then you can modify scope as per your requirement or comfort zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options here.

1. Creating a class method on the `Post` model, as you suggested. Don't forget to define it as `def self.posted_days_ago(n)` and use `self` inside the method to represent the class.
2. Use a parameter inside a scope. It will look something like this:

   ```
   scope :posted_num_days_ago, ->(n=1) {where(created_at: ((Time.now.midnight - n.days)..(Time.now.midnight - (n-1).days)))}
   ```

Notice the default value I set in this example. You may set it to whatever you need.

Comment: Then how do I call the scope in the second? Just `Post.posted_num_days_ago(2)`?

Comment: Also, do you have any idea what may be causing this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911949/why-does-a-time-math-calculation-return-one-value-in-irb-but-sends-a-diff-value ?

Comment: Yea, either way you call it just like that. Or you can call it even withought params if you just need to fall back to the default. And you already got your answer on the other issue.

Answer (score 1):

Scopes are using standard Procs known as lambdas.  You should be able to by adding a parameter to you lambda.  It would be something like:

```
scope :posted_num_days_ago -> (days_ago) {
  where(
    created_at: (
      Time.now.midnight - (days_ago + 1).day)
    )..(Time.now.midnight - days_ago.day)
  )
}
```

This may not be exact.  I haven't tested this.

But the idea is to use `-> (params) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Do as follows:

```
scope :posted_on, -> (day) { where(created_at: day.beginning_of_day..(day + 1.day).beginning_of_day)}
scope :num_posted_on, -> { posted_on.count}
```

And suppose model name is Post then call it as follows.

```
Post.posted_on(Date.today - 4.days)
```

OR (but above is better option)

```
scope :posted_yesterday, -> (n) { day  = (Time.now - n.days)
   where(created_at: (day - 1.day).beginning_of_day..day.beginning_of_day)
}
```

And call:

```
Post.posted_yesterday(4)
```