# Why does a Time math calculation return one value in IRB but sends a diff value to SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, time

I have a method in my `Post` model that looks like this:

```
  def self.num_posted_x_days_ago(n)
    start_date = Time.now.midnight - n.day
    end_date = Time.now.midnight - (n+1).day
    where(created_at: start_date..end_date).count
  end
```

When I run it in IRB, I get this:

```
> Post.num_posted_x_days_ago(8)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts"  WHERE ("posts"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-02-27 05:00:00.000000' AND '2015-02-26 05:00:00.000000')
=> 0
```

Note that the `Time` on the date is `05:00:00.000000` for both the `start_date` and `end_date`.

But when I add a `binding.pry` into the method, and inspect both the `start_date` and `end_date`, I get this:

```
1] pry(Post)> start_date
=> 2015-02-26 00:00:00 -0500
[2] pry(Post)> end_date
=> 2015-02-25 00:00:00 -0500
```

Which shows the right time starting at midnight.

When I try to do it all manually at the console, I get this:

```
[31] pry(main)> Time.now.midnight
=> 2015-03-07 00:00:00 -0500
[32] pry(main)> Time.now.midnight - 9.days
=> 2015-02-26 00:00:00 -0500
[33] pry(main)> Time.now.midnight - 9.day
=> 2015-02-26 00:00:00 -0500
```

Notice that all the times show midnight.

What could be causing this mismatch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database stores time in UTC. When you display it in console it shows you your local timezone.

Assuming you're interested in posts written on a particular day in your timezone the result should be what you expected. If you want to retrieve one day of posts in UTC timezone instead replace `Time.now.midnight` with `Time.now.utc.midnight`

---edit---

All dates stored in the database use UTC. Whenever Rails saves into database or retrieves from the database it converts from your local time zone to UTC or vice versa. That's why you see different times in SQL query. If you check the returned objects you will see that in fact these are correct results.

The only thing to keep in mind is that if you run the app on a different server it's likely that the system timezone will be different (it's a good practice to set server timezone to UTC), so `Time.now.midnight` will mean something different than on your local computer.

If you want to make sure Rails always retrieves posts from midnight of EST, you need to specify timezone explicitely:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone('EST').midnight
```

or (should switch to EDT when observing daylight saving time):

```
Time.now.in_time_zone('America/New_York').midnight
```

Comment: So if I set the local timezone in my Rails app, when I do the above calculation it should work? The issue is that the timestamps don't match. In other words, even though the database stores it in UTC, when it retrieves the record will Rails automatically adjust the time to make sure it finds the correct posts that fall within that range?

Comment: Yes it does. But to make sure results will always be correct it's best if you specify timezone explicitely, so you need to replace `Time.now.midnight` in example above with `Time.now.in_time_zone('EST').midnight` or `Time.now.in_time_zone('America/New_York').midnight` (to automatically switch to EDT when appropriate)